# How to animate a rigged character walking on a sphere?

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

I have a rigged human-like character that I need to animate walking on a sphere (a small planet).
When I pose the armature, I'd like the root bone to automatically stay aligned to the sphere's surface, just like gravity aligns people away from the centre of the planet.

Manually I can make it match roughly, but it very fiddly to change the root bone's curves so that the interpolation matches the curvature of the ground.

I think there has to be a way to use constraints to keep the armature's base perpendicular to the sphere's normals, but I can't find it.

This [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/152951/168) is the closest I've found to my problem, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to go about it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for taking the time to comment but sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I described my problem in a written form and the only link I put is to another question on this site that I think might be related (but I might be wrong)

Comment: Perhaps add a few reference images or gifs illustrating what you want to achieve, or screenshot of what you tried and where you are stuck

Comment: right, I get it. Will update it shortly